# How to get parent domain out of url no sub-domain

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying out this from a very long time, Need a JavaScript function to extract Parent domain from URL.

**Input** 
https://app.domainname.io 
http://domainname.net 
https://domainname.com 
https://app.domain.com 
https://www.google.co.in 
http://dev2-aa.domain-name.com 
https://app.domain.co.in

**Output** 
domainname.io 
domainname.net 
domainname.com 
domain.com 
google.co.in 
domain-name.com 
domain.co.in

Thank you

Comment: If you were trying, please show the code of your attempts

Answer (score 1):

This solution might not be perfect but works for your sample data:

```
function extractDomain(url) {
  return url.match(/https?:\/\/(?:\S+\.)*(\S{3,}(?:\.\S{1,3}){1,2})/)[1]
}
```

Explanation:

`https?:\/\/`: Looks for http or https

`(?:\S+\.)*`: Matches but not captures any number of subdomains

`(\S{3,}(?:\.\S{1,3}){1,2})`: Captures the domain and the TLD. In detail:

`S{3,}`: Looks for something longer which should be the domain part (eg. `google`). This is not perfect, because a 2 letters long domain name would not match.

`(?:\.\S{1,3}){1,2}`: Matches the TLD part: a single TLD (eg. `.com`) or two short parts (eg. `.co.in`).

Answer (score 0):

We could try this,

```
function getHostName(url) {
    var match = url.match(/:\/\/(www[0-9]?\.)?(.[^/:]+)/i);
    if (match != null && match.length > 2 && typeof match[2] === 'string' && match[2].length > 0) {
    return match[2];
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

function getDomain(url) {
    var hostName = getHostName(url);
    var domain = hostName;

    if (hostName != null) {
        var parts = hostName.split('.').reverse();

        if (parts != null && parts.length > 1) {
            domain = parts[1] + '.' + parts[0];

            if (hostName.toLowerCase().indexOf('.co.uk') != -1 && parts.length > 2) {
              domain = parts[2] + '.' + domain;
            }
        }
    }

    return domain;
}
```

Comment: `getDomain('https://www.google.co.in')` --> `co.in`

Comment: you are right :D